# Jquery keeps returning NaN

Tags: jquery

I have a function which keeps returning NaN. I've searched the forum and tried everything that I found but obviously I'm doing something wrong seeing my (probably) weird code :)

My code:

```
  function bakVormTotals(targetClass){
  $.getJSON('http://shop.com/cart/?format=json', function(data){
  var totaal = 0;

 $('.grandTotal').each(function(){ ////////////
 var item = $(this);               // FOUND THIS ON FORUM
 totaal+= parseInt(item.val());    ///////////
 })
 $.each(data.cart.totals, function(index, totals){
 $('<strong/>').html('€' + (+totals.grand_total).toFixed(2)).appendTo(targetClass); //  the grand total price
 });
 });
 }
```

The json looks like this: `"totals":{"sub_total":"335.29","taxes":[{"percentage":"0.1900","amount":63.71}],"grand_total":"399.00"}}`
If that may help.

Any help is greatly appreciated

**UPDATE 1**

Ok I've found some new interesting stuff. I changed the function above to:

```
  function bakVormTotals(targetClass){

  $.getJSON('http://shop.com/cart/?format=json', function(data){

  $.each(data.cart, function(index, totals){
  $('<strong/>').html('€' + totals.grand_total + '').appendTo(targetClass); // the grand total price
  });
  });
  }
```

Now the script returns: 
    €undefined€undefined€undefined€undefined€undefined€undefined€undefined€undefined€1197.00

Obviously I'm in the right direction since €1197.00 is the correct value. The "undefined" stuff is probably due to the html part?? Can some body help me changing the $('') part to something like "total" so I can leave the HTML part out?

Comment: `console.log(item.val());` and see what value is there. PS: *sometimes* it makes a bit of sense to understand what you copy-paste from "forums"

Comment: The reason is because item.val() is not a number.

Comment: Yo, do this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp ; isNan check if not a number see whats going on or paste your HTML and i might make a demo for you man! hope this gives you enough lead!

Comment: where are you getting the NaN? is it at the `<strong/>€NaN` which you're appending? or is it the value of `totaal`?

Comment: @Tats_innit: Tried this and returns: false, false, false, false, true, true

Comment: @DigitalBiscuits: I'm getting the NaN at <strong/>€NaN

Comment: @zerkms: Did something wrong with the console log. Now console log returns "item is not defined". Could for eg var item = data.totals; work?

Comment: @Jaap Vermoolen: if `console.log` returns exact string "item is not defined" - then it means that the variable contains such string

Comment: @zerkms: do you have any suggestions what to do then right now. As told I have limited jquery and json skills. I'm willing to learn so some directions are more then welcome ;) Thanks anyway

Comment: you're getting the can you give us the `€undefined` as you are trying to access a variable that doens't exist in the JSON object. 
Can you post the JSON string that you're getting from the server? that way we can look at the structure and help you query the object properly

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.grandTotal').each(function(){
  var item = $(this);               // FOUND THIS ON FORUM
  totaal+= parseInt(item.val()); 
  ...
```

In this part, you loop through a set of DOM elements. Depending on these elements, they probably do not have a function `val()`, so `item.val()` is not a number but rather `undefined`.

Comment: I think `totaal` might be a misspelling contributing to the issue as well.

Comment: That's just Dutch for 'total'. ;)

Comment: Ahh ok. It doesn't appear to be used anything though.

Comment: @asawyer: Probably this is true. Have you any suggestion how to fix this, or maybe suggestions what would be better in this situation?

Comment: How do the HTML elements with class .grandTotal look like?

Comment: @Paul: just plain HTML. Do you have any suggestions to call the "grand_total" object from the JSON string? I really can't see why this doesn't work. I have another function which calls a value exact the same way and it works without problems. This is the other function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778562/json-show-only-object-with-a-specific-id

Comment: I think you mix up some things. `$('.grandTotal')` refers to a HTML element with that class, e.g. `<input class="grandTotal" name="grandTotal" value="1197.00" />`. Whereas `totals.grand_total` refers to the JSON object. In your question you are not showing how the HTML looks like neither how you get the 1197 value. It's hard to help you without being able to reconstruct the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think lucuma is right, you need to parse to float doing parseFloat($item.val())

Comment: Tried this and it returns nothing. A blank field. Oow sorry it returns €NaN €NaN €NaN

Answer (score 0):

If you call `parseInt()` on an empty string or undefined variable, you will get a `NaN` error. I suspect this is what is happening.

Do the following check to avoid these situations:

> ```
> if(!isNaN(parseInt(item.val())))
> {
>     totaal+= parseInt(item.val());
> }
> ```

Also, just to make sure you're aware, using `parseInt()` will drop the decimal places. using `parseFloat()` will retain them.